# Difference between smarty variable scope 'root' or 'global'

Tags: smarty

Reading the documentation here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

> The scope of the assigned variable: 'parent','root' or 'global'

Well I know what global is but what does root mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says on the page you link to.

> Example 7.12. {assign} a variable to current scope tree
>
> You can assign a variable to root of the current root tree. The
>   variable is seen by all templates using the same root tree.
>
> {assign var=foo value="bar" scope="root"}

So where you call `$smarty->display("webpage.tpl");` and then assign a var with root scope in any template that may be included by webpage.tpl, that var is available to every other template included by webpage.tpl, and in webpage.tpl itself.